# Using stripe for accepting payments to from users in iOS App

Tags: stripe-payments, payment

I am developing an iOS application in which I want my user to subscribe to use some features and I am using stripe to process payments.

Is it allowed by apple, or I can only use Apple pay for accepting payments?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use Stripe to accept payments in iOS. Depending on what you're charging for though, Apple's developer terms might require you to use the [In-App Purchase API](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase). But as long as what you're charging for falls outside of the criteria laid out by Apple you should be fine. You can read more on this in Stripe's documentation here:

https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay